# Waiting Until All Items in the loop are processed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I click a button and in that for each item in a list, it goes and deletes some stuff.
My goal is to disable the button while the deleting is going on so I have a state of `isDeleting` that handles the enabled/disabled of the button.

Here is how I have set up the change of this `isDeleting` state.
But still the button becomes enabled although some delete processing is still going on.( because I can see the API of deleting is still running in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools).

How should I change my code to fully wait until everything is done before changing the state of my `isDeleting` state?

```
// Button Click
handleDeleteAllItems = async () => {
    await this.gridApiforEachNodeAfterFilter((node) => {
        this.setState({ isDeleting: true });
        node.setSelected(false);
    });
};

// This code runs for each item in the button click loop
{
    this.setRowSelectable(event.node, false);
    let Id = this.brokerFundsDict[event.data.id].id;
    fetchDeleteFund(someOtherThing.id, id).then(() => {         
        fetchGetFunds(selectedBroker.id).then(() => {
            this.setRowSelectable(event.node, true);
        });
    });
    this.setState({ isDeleting: false });
}
```

Comment: You could use a semaphore/simple counter for this. If you know the number of rows to be processed, set `counter = <number of rows>`. Then, within each deletion callback, decrement `counter` by `1`. If `counter === 0`, button is enabled - or, the other way around, if `counter > 0`, button is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) like so:

```
function deleter(someOtherThing) {
  //original: This code runs for each item in the button click loop
  return fetchDeleteFund(someOtherThing.id, id).then(() => {         
    fetchGetFunds(selectedBroker.id).then(() => {
      this.setRowSelectable(event.node, true);
    });
  });
}
```

```
function triggerDelete() {
  this.setRowSelectable(event.node, false);

  let allDeletePromises = [];
  toBeDeletedNodes.forEach(node => {
    allDeletePromises.push(deleter(node));
  });

  Promise.all(allDeletePromises)
    .then(arrOfMessages => {
       this.setState({ isDeleting: false });
    })
}
```

Comment: So in my original code in the button click there is this line of code:   node.setSelected(false);   that's the line that causes the second part of code to run.  How do I do that.

Comment: I would need some more code snippet to understand your requirements better. The code in the answer is a bit indicative and you might have to update your question to include more context and code for me to give an even more precise answer. Thank you.